# Serilog.Expressions how to use the wildcard indexing (any) operator on a dictionary

Tags: c#, serilog, serilog-expressions

I'm using Serilog.Expressions (3.4.0) to try to filter SQL injection attacks appearing in the query string. I've enriched the log event with the query string as a dictionary.  It appears in my output as:

```
QueryString: {
    someKey: "UNION ALL SELECT NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL#"
}
```

I can successfully filter by specifying the key:

```
QueryString['someKey'] like '%UNION ALL SELECT%' ci
```

However, if I change the index to the "any" wildcard, the expression no longer matches the log event:

```
QueryString[?] like '%UNION ALL SELECT%' ci
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this not supported?

Comment: This turned out to be a bug in SeriLog Expressions and has been fixed.
https://github.com/serilog/serilog-expressions/issues/76